# MySQL Server is stopped at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[Here the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxiLJ.png)

MySQL Server is stopped at runtime

Hello, use Hibernate 4 and Spring MVC for a web application, but every so often when I use the application stops the MySQL server, and I have to manually restart the service so that everything is restored.

Use the test server WamppServer, I spend the same with XAMPP and also with MySQL Community Server, which can not be happening??

Comment: Does not look like a problem with the hibernate/spring, it is the mysql server which is the culprit, try it on a different machine or new installation. Are you by any chance flooding the dbserver with gazillions of requests?

Comment: Hello, already tried it on different computers, and get the same result, in fact I do so many queries to the database, only the necessary.

Comment: remote or local db ?

Comment: now use the database locally